# How to cancel / undo my vote for a review?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, editing-help

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5467774

I clicked "vandalism" because it looked like generic attention check from `Community`, but then something ticked inside of me, and i pressed back button, just to see it was a valid edit.

Is it possible for me to change my vote ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot. Once you voted, you voted.

In this case, the OP accepted the edit to their post, so there is nothing to worry about here. For edits that end up being rejected, if it was a tie *without* your vote, you can always manually re-apply the same edit to the post.

Comment: Ok, everything's good in that case :)