# Why can we not change our review choices?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, review-suspension

I recently was working the Triage review queue and accidentally clicked on "Requires Editing" instead of "Unsalvagable". Now, I realised I had misclicked right away, but I was unable to do anything about it, as I found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258820/5015356) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267765/5015356). What is not clear from these answers, in my opinion, is why? Why not allow the choices to be changed or simply made void within a minute of their being made?

A misclick can happen to anyone, but the "Requires Editing" button in Triage is notorious for leading to reviews suspensions, since it's generally misunderstood. In fact, I also misunderstood it until I was rightfully suspended some months ago and read up on the discussions about it.

Comment: You can flag the post form outside of the review queue, thus mostly correcting your mistake.

Comment: @yivi What if you meant to click "Looks OK"? OP didn't, but I'm sure that could easily happen to someone else.

Comment: Usually, one failure won't get you review banned. If this only happened once, then you don't really need to worry. Just, as yivi said, flag the post outside the queue, and move on.

Comment: @flarn2006 Then you can retract the flag. (Although flagging incorrectly requires several clicks, so "I flagged because of a misclick" is much less credible).

Comment: @yivi No, I mean if you clicked "Requires Editing" instead of "Looks OK". Can you retract that?

Comment: @flarn2006 No, you can't. But it's not a serious problem. The difference between "requires editing" and "looks ok" is not all that great.

Comment: @10Rep In this case, it did get me suspended. As I said, I'm not against that tool (though it might be a bit harsh), but it's left me feeling a bit raw to have been suspended for a misclick without being able to do anything to make it right.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Well, it's a surprise to me. The only thing I can think of is that a mod saw your review and suspended you manually. But I think  it makes sense to unban you(as long as you didn't make more mistakes).

Comment: @Ruben review suspension is lifted... just do your best to not mis-click (although it happens!)

Comment: *"A misclick can happen to anyone"* - don't make it happen during audit. Period. Yes, it's that important to concentrate while judging others. Yes, you will be punished hard if you make a mistake. Don't make mistakes.

Comment: @Sinatr You won't be punished if you make *a* mistake, only if you make several, and only if they happen in a short period of time. I've failed many audits over the years but they are only one every couple of hundred reviews at their most frequent. This includes some occasional misclicks; you *can't* always help the rare hand spasm or misfiring muscle memory (normally such critical action UIs have a confirmation option; it's a lot of work, but I'd like to see a toggleable feature to review and then double check before "submitting", either for individual reviews or for a full set of reviews).

Comment: Worth mentioning here that [visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues/) are in the works, and they include a doing away with the current ribbon of action buttons in favor of [a set of radios with a "submit" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzo3n.png). This isn't "undo," but it *is* an answer to "I misclicked a review button."

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I don't think this would be useful: Having an "undo" option on review would end up encouraging users to be less careful with their reviews, since they could often walk back their errors.

Also, it would make review-audits kinda useless, since after failing an audit one could always say "nah, I meant the other thing".

This "feature" would make the system more complicated without bringing any real benefits.

---

On review, one should be very careful. So misclicks should not happen very often. For the most destructive kind of error (saying that's something is OK when it's actually not), the best course of action is simply to flag the item from outside the queue.

The rare misclick is not a problem that way, since one can correct the mistake without any assistance. If the misclick ends up on a review-suspension, it may mean that the user is not paying enough attention and hitting the wrong button more often than they should. The suspension is merited and useful in these cases, to help the reviewer realize that they should proceed with less haste while reviewing.

Comment: Thank you, I can see how being suspended for being overly hasty can be a good wake-up call

Comment: "_it would make review-audits kinda useless_" - What if you could only "undo" choices made on non-audits? That would still greatly reduce the risk of being stuck with a specific choice after misclicking in general.

Comment: I think I've already made an argument against that in this answer.

Comment: It could be useful to have a small window in which you can undo, kinda like how there is a small time window in which you can edit comments (and also answers without it showing up). I think one minute (maybe even less) could be a good amount of time to revert mis-clicks without causing any additional issues with the system (e.g. it doesn't count as a "real" vote until the time is up, like the "Undo" button when you send an email in Gmail), and means less flags for moderators to deal with for these trivial cases.

Comment: Do we really want users what miss keys *often* perform review? With current system (I am not aware how it works in detail) is single miss a big problem? How big?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Better yet just only let them review their choices for review items before submission, then tell them after final submission whether it was an audit (and whether it was passed or failed).

Comment: @TylerH Yes, that is a better choice

Comment: Just adding a "submit" button instead of having an immediate submission of the review on button click would "fix" this, while adding exactly zero back-end weight. This would side-step the "how long to undo" discussion. I'm not sure that the extra friction in the UI would be worthwhile however, especially for power reviewers (effectively doubling the clicks required to review would have impact), but it would help address this issue if it's a genuine concern.

Comment: maybe a "toggle between immediate submission or submit button" could do it. There's a shiny userscript in the making there.

Comment: @zcoop98 Done properly it wouldn't be much extra effort, as you could just click -> tab -> enter to submit. Of course lately SO really loves to muck up the DOM.

Comment: @TylerH how is click + 2 button presses any less effort? I would argue that it's even more, because you would have to move either your right hand from mouse -> keyboard -> mouse, or your left hand across the whole keyboard ( tab -> enter). I don't think the issue is big enough to warrant this, because it would get super annoying after a few minutes.

Comment: @Maharkus Because your hand is already on the keyboard and it's typically quicker to press two keys than move the mouse and click again. Spacebar can often be used as well for those who don't like the movement to the Enter key with their left hand, though that is minimal with Tabbing with the pinky and hitting Enter with the thumb.

Comment: *"since they could often walk back their errors"* then why not have a limited amount of walk-backs (say 3) that take a long time to replenish (5 days?), each one costing a significant amount of reputation (maybe, doubling for each walk-back)? That will discourage people from using this often. *"This "feature" would make the system more complicated without bringing any real benefits."* I doubt that.. I feel like triage is way too harsh on people trying to help. Adding an option like this might encorage new users to join triage without the fear of being banned for ages